# iPhone SDK :How to route audio output through receiver at top on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am using AVAudioPlayer in my project. When audio gets played, it uses speakers at bottom of the phone as a default route for audio output. But I want to route audio output from the iPhone receiver at top .

Answer (score 1):

[IPhone audio: Volume faint ( but okay with headphones )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818756/iphone-audio-volume-faint-but-okay-with-headphones)

Not sure if this is going to give you your solution, but it should help make you aware of the fact that the audio session defaults to playing out of the receiver when the microphone is enabled ( to avoid feedback ),  and that you can override this behaviour.

your question is actually asking the reverse of this,  but this may point you in a useful direction.

Answer (score -3):

I assume the solution is to plug in your headphones.